# Display Firebase Data on HTML Page

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to display messages on a feed using the following template called `feed.component.html`

```html
<div class="feed">
  <div *ngFor="let message of feed | async" class="message">
    <app-messages [chatMessage]="message"></app-messages>
  </div>
</div>
```

I keep getting the following error, and am unable to display the messages I send to the Firebase Database on my html chat page.

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe
>   'AsyncPipe'

I've also got my `feed.component.ts` file as follows:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { ChatMessage } from '../models/chat-message.model';
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-feed',
  templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css']
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  feed: AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]>;

  constructor(private chat: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("feed init...")
    this.feed = this.chat.getMessages();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.feed = this.chat.getMessages();
  }

}
```

I've also got my `messages.components.ts` file below:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { ChatMessage } from '../models/chat-message.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages',
  templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages.component.css']
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() chatMessage: ChatMessage;
  userName: string;
  userEmail: string;
  messageContent: string;
  timeStamp: Date = new Date();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(chatMessage = this.chatMessage) {
    this.messageContent = chatMessage.message;
    this.timeStamp = chatMessage.timeSent;
    this.userEmail = chatMessage.email;
    this.userName = chatMessage.userName;
  }

}
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong here and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Angularfire2 version? BTW, you should probably use an `Observable` instead of an `AngularFireList`. It's been removed, I think

Comment: @Edric The AngularFire2 version I'm using is angularfire2: "^5.0.0-rc.6". By Observable, you mean FirebaseListObservable?

Comment: No, just an `Observable` on `rxjs`

Comment: I'm really new to this, could you please show me how to do that? @Edric

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve the issue I was having was to change the following bit of code in the feed.component.ts file:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("feed init...")
    this.feed = this.chat.getMessages().valueChanges(); // Added `valueChanges`
}
```

I believe it then gets the object from the Firebase Database, and then ***ngFor** iterates through the object to give me the `content`, `userNames` and `timestamps` for each message.

If there's something wrong with this answer, please let me know as I'm still quite new to this.

Cheers.

---UPDATE---

Another way I found was to use a service, where I used Subject as an observable to store my response. This made it accessible to all the components, which was easier than worrying about parent-child relationships.

### Service File

```
const response = Subject();
const response$ = response.asObservable();

async getData() {
   await someApiCall.subscribe((element) => {
     this.response.next(element);
   })
 }
```

### Component.ts

```
const data = [];
getDataFromService {
    this.data = async() => this.service.getDatata();
}
```

### View

```
<div *ngFor="let i of data>
    <p>{{i | async}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The `valueChanges` method is to basically an `Observable` that emits with data whenever your database has been modified/added/updated/whatever you call it.

Comment: By the way, you can also remove your `ngOnChanges` method on your component file.

Answer (score 0):

`AngularFireList` is to store the reference path, so that you can perform `push()`, `update()` and `remove()`. You need to `subscribe` to the list to get the values. For example

```
feedRef: AngularFireList<any>;
feeds: Observable<ChatMessage[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.feedRef = this.db.list('chats');
    this.feeds = this.feedRef.valueChanges();
}
```

Beacuse you are getting reference from chat service you need to do

```
feeds: Observable<ChatMessage[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.feeds = this.chat.getMessages().valueChanges();
}
```