# How can Display AngularFireList in home.html

Tags: ionic3, angularfire2

How can I display this list please in home.html?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    school$ : AngularFireList<any[]>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.school$ = db.list('/database');

        console.log(this.school$);
    }
}
```

I tried this code but it's not working

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of school$ | async">
        <ion-card>
            <img src="assets/imgs/ensa.png"/>
            <div class="card-title">
                <span>{{data.abrev_school}} </span>
            </div> 
        </ion-card>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547793/display-firebase-data-on-html-page/49562210#49562210) pleach check.